# How long does it take for webmaster tools to update

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I have recently been going through our webmaster tools to try and boost our SEO to what it use to be. I saw that we had a lot of duplicate title tags and also Google was crawling our sort pages (so it was classing it as duplicate content). I have since addressed all these problems but webmaster tools still says that those problems exists.

So i was just wondering if there is a time i should wait before becoming nervous that my fixes haven't work or does google just do it in their own time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google notoriously takes it's own time to update the webmaster. You can do some things to try and make the changes go through a little quicker such as using the fetch as Google tool or submitting pages through the URL submit tool but in my experience changes can take a month to process properly through the webmaster, if not longer.